# How to catch UnknownHostException when connecting to websocket via OkHttp on Android?

Tags: java, android, exception, websocket, okhttp

When internet connection is provided, my app is able to connect to a server via websocket using OkHttp (v 3.9.0). I want to handle a failed attempt to connect to a websocket gracefully (i.e. when no internet connection is avaliable).

I build a connection to my server using the code presented below:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(BuildConfig.WS_URL)
        .build();

client.newWebSocket(request, webSocketListener);
```

My listener handles failure and logs UnknownHostException.

```
@Override
public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, Response response) {

    if(t instanceof UnknownHostException) {
        Log.v("LISTENER", "UNKNOWN HOST EXCEPTION");
    }
}
```

The result is

```
09-11 15:16:32.773 18384-18473/com.example.app V/LISTENER: UNKNOWN HOST EXCEPTION

09-11 15:16:32.775 18384-18473/com.example.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp https://my.server.url/...
                                                                     Process: com.example.app, PID: 18384
```

And the app crashes.

I've tried to surround the first block of code with try-catch, catching any exception thrown, but later I figured out UnknownHostException must've been already handled internally by OkHttpClient. OkHttpClient then called my listener's onFailure method. However, UnknownHostException still remains uncaught. Is there any way to catch this exception? I don't want to use `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()` . Is there any other way to handle this situation?

Comment: Why don't you try using Retrofit2 instead of OkHttp? Usually, Retrofit works for Android and OkHttp is used for "Standard Java".

Comment: UnknownHostException is never thrown inside onFailure() method.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried using OkHttp from Android to communicate with a WebSockets server a month or so ago, and it didn't want to work. So instead I used a low-level way of communicating and it worked like a charm, with just basic Java.

Here's how the code looks (for sending information to the server, in my case):

```
//this is the method that sends the String passed as the parameter to the Sockets server
    private void sendMessage(final String stringToSend) throws IOException {

    if(isOnline()){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Socket socket = null;
                try {
                    socket = new Socket("192.168.0.1",1001);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                DataOutputStream DOS = null;
                try {
                    DOS = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    DOS.writeUTF(stringToSend);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Using this low-level approach, I was able to bypass using OkHttp and did my job with just standard Java. Now, I know you want to GET data from the server and not post it, like in my case, but maybe it gives you an idea of a workaround with just Java.

Also, you might write an `isOnline()` method like I did. Only if it's online will it try to communicate with the server. Maybe that way, you'll get around your problem and keep your current code. Here's my `isOnline()` method:

```
protected boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            //if you're not connected through Wi-Fi...
            if(netInfo.getType() != ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
                Toast.makeText(this,"This app doesn't work without Wi-Fi",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

You can even make the app try to connect to a certain Wi-Fi using this:

```
    private void connectToWifi() {
        String networkSSID = "YourWiFiSSID";

        WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
        wifiConfig.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
        wifiConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);

        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);

        //enable the WiFi if it's disabled
        if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        }

        //get the list of Wi-Fi configurations
        List<WifiConfiguration> wifiConfigurationList = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
        for(WifiConfiguration configuration : wifiConfigurationList){
            //if the configuration is the right one, connect to it
            if(configuration.SSID != null && configuration.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")){
                wifiManager.disconnect();
                wifiManager.enableNetwork(configuration.networkId,true);
//                wifiManager.reconnect();

                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

UnknownHostException is subclass of [IOException](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/IOException.html%20IOException) so you can catch the IOException and this will fix it for you

Comment: I've tried surrounding the block of code responsible for connection with try {...} catch (Exception e) {...}, but it doesn't throw any exception

Comment: catch(IOException e)

Comment: IOException is a subclass of Exception.

Comment: Every exception is subclass of Exception class, give it a shot ;)

Comment: then try this please :
catch(Throwable t);

Comment: The Throwable class is the superclass of all errors and exceptions in the Java language. Only objects that are instances of this class (or one of its subclasses) are thrown by the Java Virtual Machine or can be thrown by the Java throw statement. Similarly, only this class or one of its subclasses can be the argument type in a catch clause.

if this didnt catch it then nothing will, which means you have error somewhere else.